# Unable to load a .cmd from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, save, load

I recently played the game "Dictator" and wanted to recreate it in a batch script. I just began creating it when I ran into an issue. I have made programs which allow the user to save their progress and load it. I copied this code from a different program and put it in mine. Saving does seem to work but when i edit the save file (.cmd) and edit one of the saved variables, once I load that file nothing seems to happen. For example I saved one file called key.cmd and edited it to make the "pol" variable equivalent to 100. Once I loaded that file it did say loaded but the pol variable was still set to the default (10). I dont understand as I have made a folder called save and key.cmd file is inside it. I have used my save and load code multiple times in the past and have never had any issues. Please help! Here is my code:

```
:Setup
@echo off
title Dictator
color 0a

:Save Variables
set pol=10
set bui=10
set low=10
set cor=10
set peo=10
set cri=10

:Main
cls
echo 1 - Save
echo 2 - Load
echo 3 - Police - %pol%
echo 4 - Buissnes Men - %bui%
echo 5 - Lower Government - %low%
echo 6 - Corruption - %cor%
echo 7 - People - %peo%
echo 8 - Criminals - %cri%
choice /c 12345678 /n /m ">>> "
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto Save
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto load

:Save
cls
set /p pin="PIN: "
(
echo set pol=%pol%
echo set bui=%bui%
echo set low=%low%
echo set cor=%cor%
echo set peo=%peo%
echo set cri=%cri%
) >> saves\%pin%.cmd
echo SAVED
pause >nul
goto main


:Load
cls
set /p pin="PIN: "
if exist saves\%pin%.cmd (
    call saves\%pin%.cmd
    echo %pol%
    echo LOADED
    pause >nul
) else (
    echo INCORRECT PIN
    pause >nul
)
goto main
```

Comment: you fell into the [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `:Load` you need to allow spaces in the file name. Most users won't know of this weakness, but in order to allow spaces (and a few other 'special' characters) to be read in the user input without breaking it, you need to add `setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` to the beginning of your batch file and make the `set /p pin="PIN: "` statement into `set /p "pin=PIN: "` and replace the `%`'s with `!`'s where it calls for `%pin%`.
In the end, your code should look like:

```
:Setup
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
title Dictator
color 0a

:Save Variables
set pol=10
set bui=10
set low=10
set cor=10
set peo=10
set cri=10

:Main
cls
echo 1 - Save
echo 2 - Load
echo 3 - Police - %pol%
echo 4 - Buissnes Men - %bui%
echo 5 - Lower Government - %low%
echo 6 - Corruption - %cor%
echo 7 - People - %peo%
echo 8 - Criminals - %cri%
choice /c 12345678 /n /m ">>> "
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto Save
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto load

:Save
cls
set /p "pin=PIN: "
(
echo set pol=%pol%
echo set bui=%bui%
echo set low=%low%
echo set cor=%cor%
echo set peo=%peo%
echo set cri=%cri%
) >> saves\!pin!.cmd
echo SAVED
pause >nul
goto main


:Load
cls
set /p "pin=PIN: "
if exist saves\!pin!.cmd (
    call saves\!pin!.cmd
    echo %pol%
    echo LOADED
    pause >nul
) else (
    echo INCORRECT PIN
    pause >nul
)
goto main
```

Comment: Also, in your code, you misspelled 'Business Men' as 'Buissnes Men'.

Comment: thanks for help with the typo ;P but the loading function in my game still doesn't seem to be working. I even pasted all of your code over mine and still don't have it working. The one ting that did make it work is when I changed %pol% to !pol!. Any suggestions to why this is the case or how to get around it?

Comment: @MatthewHorvath you changed `%pin%` to `!pin!`, but that isn't neccessary. The only variable in this code, that needs delayed expansion is `pol` within the `:load` subroutine